# How to detect a drop, regardless of where it occurred?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am creating a WPF application with a drag and drop functionality.

When a drag is initiated, the colors of the rectangles in my window will change from white to green or red to indicate which ones are valid drop targets.

I want to revert the colors of the rectangles back to white whenever a drop was performed, regardless of where the drop occured.

I already managed to revert the colors back when the drop occured on the drop targets. But now I can't find a way to do the same thing when the drop is performed elsewhere.

I've tried something like this, but no luck for me:

```
Private Sub Meh(sender As Object, e As QueryContinueDragEventArgs) Handles DragSource.QueryContinueDrag()
    If e.Action = DragAction.Cancel Or e.Action = DragAction.Drop Then
        For Each R as Rectangle In Rectangles.Children
            R.Fill = Brushes.White
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I even made a handler of the MouseUp event of the window to do it. Still no good.

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Don't use an event, simply restore after the DoDragDrop() call.  Also note that this method tells you whether a drop actually occurred with its return value.

Comment: That would be inappropriate since the colors are changed to green/red after that call. I want them to be restored only when the mouse button was released.